# Creating and sending an HttpResponse message

Tags: c#, httpresponse

Given either a url or a `HttpResponse` instance, I need to send back a `HttpResponse` (note *Response* not *Request*) with Status code 200. I've tried a generic `HttpClient.PostAsync` and `GetAsync`, but I can't configure the status code.

This is basically a handshake for subscribing to events for a remote service. I send a Request, get an *OK* back from the server and now it's expecting me to reply to the *OK* with my own *OK*.

Any ideas on how to go about this? I don't have an incoming request to respond to.

```
var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
// need to sent this to the url. no content necessary.
```

Here's some things I *cannot* do:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var resp = await client.GetAsync(url);
-------------------
var content = new ByteArrayContent(new byte[0]);
var client = new HttpClient();
var resp = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Comment: that's an incredibly weird way to implement HTTP, and as far as I know no "normal" HTTP implementation allows the client to *respond* to a server's response. You will probably have to dig into the sockets layer and implement this yourself.

Comment: Definitely strange and not in line with how HTTP is supposed to work. How can you have a Response without a Request? Even stranger, what type of server is expecting a Response without having send a Request?

Comment: Check if the initial response does not contain a header that tells you where you should send a request for the handshake.  Is this required for events in CloudEvents schema by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `HttpClient` calls you are creating `HttpRequestMessage`s.  There are a number of helper methods (like some `PostAsync` overloads or `PostAsJsonAsync`) which let you pass in a plain old C# object, which it then wraps for you.  These values get set in the `Content` property of the `HttpRequestMessage`, wrapped by an instance of `HttpContent`.  You're also perfectly free to create these request messages yourself, setting the status code and content to anything you like.  `HttpResponseMessage` (note `Response`, not `Request`) is the type you'll get back from your client call, which you can use to read the response code or data sent back to you (stored in `HttpResponseMessage.Content`, not to be confused with `HttpRequestMessage.Content`, which you would have already set).

That said, you CAN set your request content to an instance of `HttpResponseMessage`, but that would be a little bit odd.  Generally, the objects you use for your content should be simple objects which exist simply to define the shape of your requests' body (like JSON).

This article goes over the basics pretty well: [Calling a Web API from a .Net Client](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Answer (score 0):

```
return StatusCode(200, "optional message");
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to set the status directly on the HttpResponse object
Something like this...

`HttpResponse().StatusCode = 200;`

Comment: but can I just create a `HttpResponse` and post it to a url? That's the question.